# Show that $5^m+5^k$ is not a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that $5^m+5^k$ is not a square($m,k$ positive integers)

First I thought showing $5^m+5^k$ has a right digit other than $0,1,4,9,6,5$ is sufficient but I was wrong! It's just necessary not sufficient.
Then assumning $m>k\ $  I wrote it as $5^k(5^{m-k}+1)$ and now clearly $k$ must be even, but what about $5^{m-k}+1$??

Comment: It is sufficient, but you can't show it.

Comment: Counter Example: $10$ is not a square!!

Comment: No, you said showing that $12$ has a right digit **other than** $0,1,4,9,6,5$ is sufficient, which it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show that $5^{m-k}+1$ is not a square. Assume $5^{m-k}+1=a^2.$ So

$$5^{m-k}=a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1).$$ So, $a-1$ and $a+1$ must divide $5.$ Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Hint. You cant have an $x$ such that $x^{2}\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: S.C : Why to choose modulus 4?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: Because it works! (What is $5^m \bmod 4$?)

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Because, take any $x$ its even or odd. If its even then $x=2n$ then we have $x^{2}=4n^{2}=0\pmod{4}$. And if $x$ is odd, then $x=2n+1$, so $x^{2}=(2n+1)^{2}=1\pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $[n^2\equiv\color\red0\pmod4]\vee[n^2\equiv\color\green1\pmod4]$:

- $n\equiv0\pmod4 \implies n^2\equiv0^2\equiv\color\red0\pmod4$
- $n\equiv1\pmod4 \implies n^2\equiv1^2\equiv\color\green1\pmod4$
- $n\equiv2\pmod4 \implies n^2\equiv2^2\equiv\color\red0\pmod4$
- $n\equiv3\pmod4 \implies n^2\equiv3^2\equiv\color\green1\pmod4$

Then, note that $[5^m+5^k\not\equiv\color\red0\pmod4]\wedge[5^m+5^k\not\equiv\color\green1\pmod4]$:

- $5^m+5^k\equiv(5\bmod4)^m+(5\bmod4)^k\equiv1^m+1^k\equiv1+1\equiv\color\orange2\pmod4$

Comment: Can we use this technique to show for example $6^m+6^k$ is not a square?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: Why don't you plug in $6$ instead of $5$ and see what happens?

Comment: Although your answer is also quite correct, since mfl answer is near my technique I accept that, thank you very much for detailed explanation:)

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: You're welcome :)